# React js fill a map using axios inside a for loop

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to visualize a line chart (using canvas js) in react Js project , so i'm getting a data using axios get request and im looping this request to fill a data variable that is used as input to the line chart , but my problem is that axios seems to fill my data randomly

This is my code inside `componentdidmount()` :

```
     constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: [] ,

    };
  }
       componentDidMount(){
    let responses = []
    for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
      responses.push(axios.get("http://localhost:5000/transfer/getUsesByDay/"+i).then(res =>{
          return res.data
      }))
    }
      Promise.all(responses).then(results => {
    console.log(results)
    this.setState(prevState => {
      return {

            data: [...prevState.data, ...results.map(r => r)]


         };
        })
      }
      )
```

And this is the render function :

```
    render() {
    const { data: chartData } = this.state;
    const { classes } = this.props;
    {console.log(chartData)}
    return (
      <Paper>
        <Chart
          data={chartData}
          className={classes.chart}
        >
```

Now , when i execute i get this result( console.log(results)) :

```
0: {year: "15", utilisation: 3}
1: {year: "12", utilisation: 0}
2: {year: "12", utilisation: 0}
3: {year: "09", utilisation: 1}
4: {year: "08", utilisation: 1}
5: {year: "10", utilisation: 5}
6: {year: "09", utilisation: 1}
7: {year: "10", utilisation: 0}
```

And then when i re-execute i get another result like this :

```
0: {year: "11", utilisation: 3}
1: {year: "10", utilisation: 0}
2: {year: "10", utilisation: 0}
3: {year: "09", utilisation: 1}
4: {year: "09", utilisation: 1}
5: {year: "09", utilisation: 5}
6: {year: "08", utilisation: 1}
7: {year: "08", utilisation: 0}
```

And the result should be ordered like this :

```
0: {year: "14", utilisation: 3} // the result of http://localhost:5000/transfer/getUsesByDay/"+i when i == 0 , and so on
1: {year: "13", utilisation: 0}
2: {year: "12", utilisation: 0}
3: {year: "11", utilisation: 1}
4: {year: "10", utilisation: 1}
5: {year: "09", utilisation: 5}
6: {year: "08", utilisation: 1}
7: {year: "07", utilisation: 0}
```

Comment: This is not an `axios` or `react` problem. The dev responsible for the API should ensure the order of the content or you can order yourself when you process the result.

Comment: Thank you samura , but how is that , i don't think that the problem is with the api beacause the api is just returning one object.

Comment: can you check your network tab? which requests are made

Comment: They all are executed in order

Comment: I solved this this problem by adding async and await logic before axios get request

Answer (score 0):

Some of your responses were responded latter even they were requested first because things happened on internet (data was lost and it had to send again,etc)

Comment: Thank you usualUserName, i get that but in this cas i will not get a full map with 7 objects , it seems like it executes the same api more then once or it fills the map  randomlly

Answer (score 0):

In your problem, you have written that you are doing

```
console.log(res.data)
```

but that is not visible in your code. By guessing I can see that you have used res variable name in

```
then(res =>{
      return res.data
 })
```

if you would have done the console.log in the above statement, it will just depend on the response of each call and the order outputted may be random each time.

Comment: Thank you Beowulf, i edited my question . i did  console.log(results) not console.log(res.data)